# Count relations in a specific domain

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

I have two groups $A=\{6,7,8,9\}, \ B=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.
I want to count how many relations there are from $A$ to $B$ which obey to the rule:

> $\{6,7,8\}\subseteq \text{domain}(k)$ 
>   * k is the relation

I have tried to count all the relations that contain {6} (2^5 - 1 ?) and then {7} (2^5 - 1 ?) and then {8} (2^5 - 1 ?) and then {6,7} and so on... but it got so messy so i left it.
I think there is a better approach to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you just wanna make sure each element of $\{6,7,8\}$ has  at least one arrow, this means for each of $6,7,8$ we have $2^5-1$ options for its image. and for $9$ we have $2^5$ options, therefore the answer is $(2^5-1)^32^5=953,312$

Which is interesting because if we dropped that restriction there would be $2^{20}=1048576$ relations, so most relations satisfy that condition.

Comment: Thanks what did you mean by arrow?

Comment: Well, you can look at relations like functions, only in relations the elements of the domain can only have one arrow pointing to the other set, but in relations you can have many arrows coming out.